# How to get github pages to open specific page on clicking the githubp pages link

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

So as the question says when I open the app locally it opens on the home page because of this code (Link to the website launchpage - https://geekstreak.github.io/geekstreak-portfolio/)

```
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

However, now I have deployed to the github pages my website no longer starts on this page, I'm aware this is probably because I need to change the home page link but I do not know how to get this to work as I am new to github pages. This is the link to my github page if needed https://github.com/GeekStreak/geekstreak-portfolio

Comment: Why don't you simply use https://geekstreak.github.io ?

Comment: I get an error saying site not found

Comment: I saw it when I commented, now it is not available anymore. Did you change something?

Comment: havent changed anything